# Enterprise-Level Hosts for Joomla

Tags: joomla

Can someone recommend an enterprise-level host that offers a complete, integrated Joomla package? It seems like most Joomla hosts are aimed at smaller sites/companies. Are there large hosts out there than can handle large Joomla installs with enterprise-level reliability?

Comment: This isn't a programming related question, so should be aimed elsewhere. Look around on Google else look at the host that the official Joomla site uses. They have been know to be very reliable ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official host](http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla/the-project/partners.html) for the Joomla! Project is [Rochen](http://www.rochenhost.com/).

I also had a good experience with [cloudaccess.net](http://www.cloudaccess.net/) - they are also focusing on Joomla hosting.

Have a look at them and get back to us with some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by "complete, integrated Joomla package".

But based on your requirements i can recommend you to get a [Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com/) VPS.

Is highly reliable, and have good prices.

I have been using it since December 2011 and it's been down only for ~1 day, in almost a year. 
I'm currently running 8 different joomla sites, 2 of them summing over 5.000 visits/day, with heavy sql and data transfer usage.
im currently paying around 35$/month for a vps bundle (600 Mb Ram VPS + mysql VPS).

I think they are giving 1 or 2 weeks free to try it out.